# Getting an element HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML document like this

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="test_id"> First element </div>
    <div> Second element </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can access first `div` element via `getElementById` but can I access somehow Second element?

Comment: `var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");` or you could try ... `document.querySelectorAll("div[id='']");`, you get the idea.

Comment: The specific selectors you need will almost certainly change if the document has more than those two nodes -- `getElementByTagName("div")[1]` will only work if the div you want is the second one in the document; using `nextSibling` will only work if it immediately follows #test_id, etc.  If you can't assign an ID or classname to the element you're looking for, you'll need to find a landmark in the existing document that you can guarantee won't change relative to the div you're trying to select, and base your selector on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with ***specific index*** like the following way:

```js
var secondDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div')[1];
console.log(secondDiv);
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="test_id"> First element </div>
    <div> Second element </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FINALLY! Someone else who actually thinks using query selector's is the best method!

Comment: Of course, if the HTML changes, then this code breaks. This is why we have `id` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You can try :

```
var x = document.getElementById("test_id").nextSibling
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("div")` returns all divs into a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object, the first div is `0` second div is `1`:

```js
var second = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1]

console.log(second.innerHTML)
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="test_id"> First element </div>
    <div> Second element </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation. Those that explain why the answer works are even better because they help folks understand the answer in a way that they can avoid the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
get Parent Element then count to your desired element then read by it name,

```
document.getElementById("test_id").parentElement.getElementByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;
```

Method 2:
direct count to div like mentioned but in some cases it won't works

```
document.getElementByTagName("div")[1]
```